How to force a product of two i.i.d. random variable to be gaussian
This question is related to this other question of mine: I realized that my original question was maybe too abitious, and I would like to discuss a much more limited version of it.

Consider two real random variables indipendent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) $X,Y$. Now consider the random variable $Z$ given by:
$$Z=XY, \tag{1}$$
how should X and Y be (identically) distributed to have $Z$ be destributed as a gaussian (normal distribution) with mean equal to $0$ and variance equal to $\sigma ^2$?

I found no theory on the topic: some bibliographical references, if they exist, will be also much apreciated.

Is this the same question? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199667/square-root-of-normal-distribution

The answer to the general case (product of $n$ iid random variables) is given in (2) of this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.09838
